# $H_2(\partial V)=0$ if $V$ is a rational homology 4-ball

Tags: algebraic-topology

I’m reading “On knots” by L. Kauffman.
In Chapter XVII (which follow the prominent paper of Casson and Gordon,) we have the following lemma.

Lemma 17.3. Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$-homology 4-ball. If the image of $H_1(\partial V)\to H_1(V)$ has order $l$, then $H_1(\partial V)$ has order $l^2$.

In the very first part of the proof, we have the following series of isomorphisms.
$$ H_2(\partial V) \cong H^1(\partial V)\cong \mathrm{Hom}(H_1(\partial V),\mathbb{Z})=0$$

Okay, the first isomorphism is the Poincaré duality for the closed manifold $\partial V$, and the second isomorphism is the universal coefficient theorem. The third isomorphism is the one I cannot see. It seems to be relevant with the fact that $V$ is a rational homology 4-ball, but how should I extract information on the homology of $\partial V$ from this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can prove this if $V$ is compact and orientable.  Is that part of the definition of $\mathbb{Q}$-homology ball?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer only works under the additional assumption that $V$ is compact and orientable.  But I thought it was useful to post nonetheless.  I first claim:

**Proposition:** If $V$ is a compact orientable rational homology $n$-ball, then $\partial V$ is a rational homology $(n-1)$-sphere.

**Proof**:  To see this, consider the LES in rational cohomology for the pair $(V,\partial V)$.  A portion looks like $$...\rightarrow H_k(\partial V;\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow H_k(V;\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow H_k(V,\partial V; \mathbb{Q})\rightarrow ...$$

Since $H_k(V;\mathbb{Q}) = 0$ for $k > 0$, this gives isomorphisms $H_{k+1}(V,\partial V;\mathbb{Q})\cong H_k(\partial V;\mathbb{Q})$ for any $k > 0$.  On the other hand, by [Poincare-Lefshetz duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_duality) (which requires compactness and orientability), $H_{k+1}(V,\partial V;\mathbb{Q})\cong H^{\dim V-(k+1)}(V;\mathbb{Q})$ and the latter group is isomorphic to $H_{\dim V -(k+1)}(V;\mathbb{Q})$ by universal coefficients.  Since $V$ is a rational homology sphere, $H_{\dim V - (k+1)}(V;\mathbb{Q}) = 0$ unless $k+1 = \dim V$, when it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Since $\dim \partial V = \dim V - 1$, we conclude $$H_k(\partial V;\mathbb{Q}) \cong H_{k+1}(V,\partial V;\mathbb{Q})\cong H_{\dim V -(k+1)}(V;\mathbb{Q})\cong \begin{cases} \mathbb{Q} & k=0, \dim \partial V\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$  So, $\partial V$ is a rational sphere.  $\square$

Armed with this proposition, for $n\geq 2$, a rational homology sphere $\partial V$ has $H_1(V;\mathbb{Q}) = 0$, so that, in particular, $H_1(V;\mathbb{Z})$ is entirely torsion.  Since $\mathbb{Z}$ has no torsion, and my $H_1(V;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ must be trivial.  Thus, $Hom(H_1(\partial V;\mathbb{Z}), \mathbb{Z})=0$ as claimed in the paper.

Comment: $V$ is a finite branced cyclic covering of a closed orientable 4-manifold in the setups, so it works! So the Poincaré-Lefschetz was the key. Thanks for your answer.